# Angular2 error: EXCEPTION susbscribe is not a function

Tags: angularjs, httpmodule

I am trying to inject a service to get information from the jsonplaceholder RESTful API into a component. I keep getting the error below:

```
EXCEPTION: Error in ./AppComponent class AppComponent_Host - inline template:0:0 caused by: this._postService.getPosts(...).susbcribe is not a function
```

Here is my code:

```
 app.module.ts:
 import { BrowserModule }           from '@angular/platform-browser';
 import { HttpModule, JsonpModule } from '@angular/http';
 import { AppComponent }            from './app.component';

 import { PostService }             from './post.service';


 @NgModule({
   imports:      [ BrowserModule, HttpModule, JsonpModule ],
   declarations: [ AppComponent ],
   bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ],
   providers:    [ PostService ]
 })

 export class AppModule { }
```

app.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { PostService }  from './post.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: ``
})

export class AppComponent { 
    constructor(private _postService: PostService){
        this._postService.getPosts()
            .susbcribe(posts => console.log(posts));
    }
}
```

post.service.ts:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http} from '@angular/http';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable();

export class PostService {

    private _url = "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";

    constructor(private _http: Http){
    }

    getPosts(){
        return this._http.get(this._url)
            .map(res => res.json());
    }

    createPost(post){
        return this._http.post(this._url, JSON.stringify(post))
            .map(res => res.json());
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got a typo:

```
susbcribe
```

instead of

```
subscribe
```

Comment: ;) we all get tired sometimes. Remember to mark it as the correct answer :)